# Terminal won't run any commands

Tags: python, linux, bash

I'm just learning how python flask works and one of the requirements is to install virtualenv, so I did `$ pip install virtualenv` then `$ pip install virtualenvwrapper` then `$ mkvirtualenv myenv`. So I get an error message that `mkvirtualenv command not found`.

I tried a couple of things I googled online on how to fix the error, I found these instructions on stackoverflow,

```
$ nano ~/.bash_profile
$ export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
$ export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh 
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

but still same error message. When i restarted my terminal the message `-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory` keeps printing itself infinitely unless I press ctrl-C, after which any command I enter i receive the message

```
-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python: Argument list too long
```

How can I restore the functionality of terminal back to normal after this?

Comment: What were the "couple things" you googled that you tried?

Comment: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` seems more OSX than Linux

Comment: BTW, "argument list too long" can be caused if you've `export`ed too many (or excessively large) environment variables -- they live in the same space that command-line arguments do. Or, of course, if a script that you've invoked has had that effect.

Comment: That said, on a stock, clean system, `/usr/local/bin` will be empty, and your user account (and thus any invocation of `pip` you run without `sudo`) won't have permission to put something there. So if you *do* have things in there, they weren't put in by any of the commands given in the question, unless you misrepresented how they were run (using `sudo` but not putting that in the question), *or* you've used software (like Homebrew on MacOS) that weakened your operating system's permissions/security model.

Comment: Anyhow -- if your shell is bash, `declare -p` will print all variables; ones with `-x` by the definition are exported to the environment. If you figure out what's eating up all your available environment space from that list (and it's not something important like `PATH`), you can just `unset` it. (If it *is* something important, you'll want to define a new, shorter value).

Comment: It's not clear what the contents of your ~/.bash_profile is after the changes you've made.  But if you have `source ~/.bash_profile` in there, that's where your infinite loop exists.